# On Linux, is there an rc.local equivalent for shutdown?

Tags: linux, startup, shutdown

I've got a few commands that I run in `rc.local` so they are run last in the startup sequence. I would like to know if there is a similar facility for undoing the results of those commands at shutdown, like an `rc.shutdown`. Ideally, it would be run before any of the other `/etc/init.d` scripts.

Comment: This is highly distribution-dependent. Please add information about your distribution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really (at least, to my knowledge).

If you've got SystemV style init scripts, you could create something along the lines of `/etc/rc6.K00scriptname` and `/etc/rc0.d/K00scriptname`, which should get executed prior to any of the other scripts in there.

Answer (score 4):

[ArchLinux](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_VServer#.2Fetc.2Frc.shutdown) does have a `/etc/rc.local.shutdown` file for this. I'm not sure about other distros

Answer (score 3):

It is generally possible, but depends on the init-scripts system you have. If your distribution used a recent version of [OpenRC](http://roy.marples.name/projects/openrc) (as Gentoo does), you could put any scripts in `/etc/local.d/`, call them `<something>.stop` and they would be run at system shutdown. For older versions, you'd have to put your commands inside `local_stop()` function in `/etc/conf.d/local`.

The order depends on the rc-system settings, but typically the *local* scripts are the last to run at startup and first to run at shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

If you have upstart, you can catch the shutdown event and run a script when it is caught.

Answer (score 1):

In [Gentoo](http://gentoo.org) the "local" script does exactly what you ask for: It runs certain user specified commands upon 'start' and another set of commands upon 'stop'.